# How to show PHP output in netbeans IDE output window, NOT in web browser

Tags: php, netbeans

I would like to run PHP file or code in neatbeans and to show the output in the output console, like in zend framework F5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the file you want to work with. Right click on the name of the project on the project tab on the upper left corner of the netbeans window. Select Set Configuration > Customize, click on the Run Configuration. From the run as drop down menu select script(run in command line)

From the options window select php tab. Set the location of your php 5 interpreter and activate the output window / editor check box.

Comment: thank you very much, just in case you are using linux you should not add the -a to the php command and the php path should be in/usr/bin/php